# Migrating google analytics to SDK Firebase : can I keep my actual property?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

I received an email from google analytics explaining me that I must migrate to SDK Firebase.

They told me : 
"Starting October, we will begin to decommission properties that were identified at the time of our first notice as receiving data exclusively from the Google Analytics Services SDK.
•   Data collection and processing for such properties will stop October 31, 2019.
•   Reporting access through our UI and API access will remain available for these properties’ historical data until January 31, 2020.
•   After our service is fully turned down in February, 2020, these properties will no longer be accessible via our Google Analytics UI or API, and their data will be removed from Google Analytics servers. You will receive further notification as these deadlines approach."

So, I install the SDK Firebase in my app, keeping the same property in analytics.

My question is : Should I have created a new property? How can I be sure that Google will not delete it?

Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is **properties ... receiving data exclusively from the Google Analytics Services SDK**. The [Sunsetting the Google Analytics Services SDKs, Firebase Help](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9167112?hl=en) page has better wording

> If you have properties that receive app data (no web, no Measurement Protocol) **only** from those SDKs

There is no need to create a new property if you are receiving data from the new source, the Firebase SDK.

Comment: OK I understand. Thanks a lot @ersin-ertan for the clarifications ! :-)